# SELECT all distinct rows with two simple characteristic

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table in 18c Oracle Database:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA
(
  COLUMNA  NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  COLUMNB  NUMBER(5) NOT NULL
)
```

I've this rows:

```
Insert into TABLEA
   (COLUMNA, COLUMNB)
 Values
   (96, 1011),
   (96, 9130),
   (848, 1011),
   (848, 1172),
   (1095, 1011),
   (1095, 1172);
```

It should be very simple but I really stuck here.
I need to get all the different values of `COLUMNA`, when all `COLUMNB` from the same `COLUMNA` are in (1172, 1011, 1037).

Result expected:

```
   COLUMNA 
---------- 
       848       
      1095
```

The value 96 shouldn't be returned, because there are a row with a value in `COLUMNB` that aren't in the condition.

Those values (1172, 1011, 1037) can be in a specific table with a single column if it helps.

I've tried this, but I just want the distinct values:

```
  SELECT columnA, COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY columnA)
    FROM tableA
   WHERE EXISTS
             (SELECT 1
                FROM tableB -- With (1172, 1011, 1037) in each row
               WHERE COLUMNB = values)
GROUP BY COLUMNA
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```

Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use DISTINCT to show non repeated values.

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnA FROM tableA WHERE columnB in (1172, 1011, 1037)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns the 96. I just want the rows where all line from the same COLUMNA have all COLUMNB in (1172, 1011, 1037)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like so, not 100% it's late here :)

```
select
columna
from
#tablea
group by columna
having count(*)=sum(case when columnb in (1172, 1011, 1037) then 1 else 0 end)
```